# How to make vertical scrolling on the page?

Tags: jquery, html

There is a form and a table on html-page 
The data from the form are added to the table and a new row is added.
When you add 20th line, you should see the vertical scroll in a browser.
Tell me, please, how to do it?
I'm beginner.

```
 <form>
  <input type="text" id="inputID"/>
  <select id = "selectID">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</form>
<button id="addNewField">Add new field</button>
<table id="container" border = "2" width = "550px">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Action</td>             
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#addNewField').click(function(){
      var inputVar = $('#inputID').val(),
          selectVar = $('#selectID').val(),
          tr = $('<tr></tr>'),
          td1 = $('<td></td>').append(inputVar),
          td2 = $('<td></td>').append(selectVar);
      tr.append(td1)
      tr.append(td2)            
      tr.appendTo('tbody', '#container')
      $('#inputID').val('');
    })
    var n = $("tr").size();
    if(n > 20) {
      $('body').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: [It *does* scroll](https://jsfiddle.net/ns4zyzow/). In some browsers, the scrollbar is only visible when you're scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only checking the number of `tr` elements once. You should check every time after adding a row to your table.

Also, [jQuery's `size()`](https://api.jquery.com/size/) method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.8, use the `.length` property in stead.

```
$(function() {
  $('#addNewField').click(function() {
    var inputVar = $('#inputID').val(),
      selectVar = $('#selectID').val(),
      tr = $('<tr></tr>'),
      td1 = $('<td></td>').append(inputVar),
      td2 = $('<td></td>').append(selectVar);
    tr.append(td1);
    tr.append(td2);
    tr.appendTo('tbody', '#container');
    $('#inputID').val('');

    // Execute this each time after adding
    // check the nr of td's using .length
    if ($("tr").length > 2) {
      $('body').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
    }
  })
});
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/48mnmyq7/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should set the table into a div and let that one scroll to make it work. set an overflow-y:scroll to the div and that should do it. If you want the scrollbar to only show up when needed, use auto.

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll;">
  <table>

  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.........

```
  $('#addNewField').click(function(){
  var inputVar = $('#inputID').val(),
      selectVar = $('#selectID').val(),
      tr = $('<tr></tr>'),
      td1 = $('<td></td>').append(inputVar),
      td2 = $('<td></td>').append(selectVar);
  tr.append(td1)
  tr.append(td2)            
  tr.appendTo('tbody', '#container')
  $('#inputID').val('');
  var n = $("#container tr").length;
  if(n == 20) {
    $("#container").css("height",20*parseInt($("#container tr")[0].css("height"))+"px").css("overflow-y","scroll");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not setting 'overflow-y' inside the click function. Try this

```
$(function() {
var n = $("tr").size();
if(n > 20) {
  $('body').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
}
$('#addNewField').click(function(){
  var inputVar = $('#inputID').val(),
      selectVar = $('#selectID').val(),
      tr = $('<tr></tr>'),
      td1 = $('<td></td>').append(inputVar),
      td2 = $('<td></td>').append(selectVar);
  tr.append(td1)
  tr.append(td2)            
  tr.appendTo('tbody', '#container')
  $('#inputID').val('');
  n = $("tr").size();
  if(n > 20) {
  $('body').css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
}
})
```

});